# How to fix the 5.0.x Lollipop OutOfMemory issue?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-5.0-lollipop

So I finished coding my app recently, and when publishing it, I got messages from friends who couldn't or only could partly run the app without crashing.

Turns out, these friends had Lollipop 5.0.x, 5.1.1 seems to work again.

I am aware of the bug from Android, my question is just, how did other programmers make their apps work on these versions? Are there common mistakes which can be avoided?

In my app I get an OutOfMemory exception when using *ImageView.setImageResource(R.id.imageResource)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This always happen when the application is out of allocation memory.

Try `android:largeHeap="true"` in your 'application' tag at manifest file to using Heap memory

** This won't working on pre-Honeycomb devices.

Answer (score 1):

you probably are setting the dimensions of the image manually or not setting them at all.
You should resize the images according to the screen size.